# What is the maximum version of iOS compatible with the 2nd-generation iPod Touch?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ipod

I got an iPod Touch 2nd-gen. (Model # MC086LL) and all the fun games I find in the App Store require iOS 4.3. Is it possible for me to upgrade it to 4.3?

Comment: Does this post help isolate the OS versions for your iPod? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55180/which-8gb-ipod-touch-do-not-support-ios-5

Comment: Or this? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/can-a-2nd-generation-ipod-touch-be-upgraded-past-2-2-1

Comment: So 4.2.1 is the highest it can be upgraded?

Answer (score 5):

iOS 4.2.1 (8C148) is the maximum OS version it can be upgraded to so you won't be able to install 4.3 or newer OS using iTunes and Apple supplied versions of the software.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 4.2.1 is the highest iTunes can install on that model.
You can't get the latest greatest apps but there are tons of vintage apps available, even for models that can only run iOS 4.2.1 or earlier.  The trick is finding them.  This is one way,
https://sites.google.com/site/appleclubfhs/support/advice-and-articles/finding-apps-for-older-devices
Then there is an app to find these vintage apps,
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vintapps-3.1.3/id639274910?mt=8&uo=4