# Is Whited00r safe? If I use it to install iOS 7, can I restore to iOS 4?

Tags: ios, software-update

I have the iPod 2nd gen and it is pretty much useless as I cannot update to IOS 7 from 4.2, BUT there is this program called [whited00r](http://www.whited00r.com/index?lang=en) which lets you update to IOS 7. Apparently it has worked with people- so, is it safe and if I do install IOS 7 and it doesnt work, can I revert back to IOS 4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum version of iOS compatible with the 2nd-generation iPod Touch?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93700/what-is-the-maximum-version-of-ios-compatible-with-the-2nd-generation-ipod-touch)

Comment: @Tetsujin This question is asking about a pseudo-upgrade called Whited00r. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson - my vote was on the initial question. It was almost completely re-written afterwards :/

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, I didn't even notice. My bad.

Comment: No worries - I upvoted your answer as actually that was new info to me [not that I have any old devices to try it on] :)  I pulled my close vote as WhiteD00r makes it no longer a dupe.

Comment: Yeah, mb, I changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whited00r is not iOS 7. It just looks and feels like iOS 7. You won't be able to install iOS 7 applications or have access to many of the features of iOS 7. You're still running iOS 4 under the hood, and all you have to do is restore in iTunes if you don't like it.